# Google Script: Create PDF with multiple pages from the same Goolge Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to export a PDF from Google Sheets with a script. Exporting a single page works fine so far. But i would like to export different ranges each on a single page in the same PDF.
Could you help me how to make this work?

I am new to script and modified this code from examples I found online. So no idea if this is even possible.

In my code I get the table from A1:I44 and export it on a single page as a pdf. This works fine.
But now I would like to add the range A51:I94 on a second page in the same PDF.

Help is much aprecciated!

```
function savePdfRechnung() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet =  ss.getSheetByName('HN_Vorlage');
var rngStr = 'A1:I44';
  var inputs = sheet.getRange('O5:O23').getValues();
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + ss.getId() + '/export?format=pdf&exportFormat=pdf&size=A4&portrait=true&scale=4&top_margin=0&left_margin=0&right_margin=0&bottom_margin=0&range=' + rngStr + '&gid=' + 1929278749;
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers:{Authorization:"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
  var contents = result.getBlob(); //.getContent();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(inputs[1][0]);
  DriveApp.createFile(contents).setName(inputs[0][0] + ".pdf").moveTo(folder);
}

function fetch(url) {
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  var result = cache.get(url);
  if(!result) {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    result = response.getContentText();
    cache.put(url, result, 21600);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to export 2 ranges of "A1:I44" and "A51:I94" from a sheet of `1929278749` of sheet ID as a PDF file including 2 pages using Google Apps Script.
- In your question, your showing function `fetch(url)` is not related to your question.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, I used [my sample script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2023/01/10/merging-multiple-pdf-files-as-a-single-pdf-file-using-google-apps-script/).

#### Modified script:

```js
async function savePdfRechnung() {
  var sheetId = "1929278749"; // This sheet ID is from your showing script.
  var ranges = ['A1:I44', 'A51:I94']; // These ranges are from your question.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var data = ranges.map(r => {
    var url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ssId}/export?format=pdf&exportFormat=pdf&size=A4&portrait=true&scale=4&top_margin=0&left_margin=0&right_margin=0&bottom_margin=0&range=${r}&gid=${sheetId}`;
    return new Uint8Array(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token } }).getContent());
  });

  // Load pdf-lib.js
  var cdnUrl = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnUrl).getContentText().replace(/setTimeout\(.*?,.*?(\d*?)\)/g, "Utilities.sleep($1);return t();"));
  // Merge PDF data.
  var pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(data[i]);
    var pages = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [...Array(pdfData.getPageCount())].map((_, i) => i));
    pages.forEach(page => pdfDoc.addPage(page));
  }
  var bytes = await pdfDoc.save();
  var contents = Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, "sample.pdf");

  // PDF blob is created as a file. This is from your showing script.
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('HN_Vorlage');
  var inputs = sheet.getRange('O5:O23').getValues();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(inputs[1][0]);
  DriveApp.createFile(contents).setName(inputs[0][0] + ".pdf").moveTo(folder);
}
```

- When this script is run, the ranges of `['A1:I44', 'A51:I94']` of a sheet of sheet ID `1929278749` are converted to PDF data. And, 'A1:I44' and 'A51:I94' are created as 1st and 2nd pages, respectively.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your sheet ID of `1929278749` is valid sheet ID, and your script for creating a file from a blob at the bottom script works fine. Please be careful about this.

Comment: So far this worked great but I have encountered a problem. When I have a cell that contains more text than can be fit on a A4 Page, the text out of bounce just vanishes. Is there a way to get the overlaping text on a new page? Much like when printing a file.

Comment: @godspeed About your new question, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?